# Comparing a float and an int in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to see if the calculated distance between two points is smaller than a given radius like this:

```
if distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) < radius:
      print "Distance: %s Radius: %s" % (distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2), radius)
```

Here `distance` would effectively return a `float` and `radius` is an `int`.

I do know that I should not compare floats directly and that I should compare with a threshold. Given that, is there a better way to check if a float is less than an int (or another float).

**Update**
This comparison seems to be ok from all of the replies. But I did observe this:

```
>>> 1.2000000000000001 > 1.2
True
>>> 1.20000000000000001 > 1.2
False
```

Isn't this a problem? I am using Python 2.6.7 on Mac

Comment: You shouldn't, in general, compare floats for *equality* without some care, but comparing floats for relativity (> or <) is perfectly fine.

Comment: Your update is due to [precision errors](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) - they are a fact of computing, and shouldn't matter to you in 99.9% of cases as they difference is too small to care about. If they do, look into the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Comment: @Lattyware - They matter in comparisons. See the link in my answer below. Floats are tricky. It's wrong to think they are easily compared. http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: What is your definition of matter? In most cases the answer being wrong due to ``0.0000000001`` really won't matter. There are some cases (e.g: ``while not x == 0.9:``, ``x += 0.3``) but these can be handled by doing more sane checks (``<`` in this case). In any other case, it'll be caught on the next loop or the error won't be an issue as it's too small.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just compare them directly, there is no harm in that at all.

Python handles comparing numbers of different types perfectly well:

```
>>> type(1.1)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> 1.1 > 1
True
>>> 1.1 < 1
False
>>> 1 < 2
True
>>> 2.2 == 2.2
True
>>> 2 == 2.2
False
>>> 1.6 < 2
True
>>> 1.6 > 2
False
>>> 1.6 == 2
False
```

Python is duck typed, so in general you shouldn't worry about types directly, just if they can work in the way you need.

There could be some issues with comparing floats for *equality* with other floats due to [precision errors](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

```
>>> 0.3+0.3+0.3 == 0.9
False
>>> 0.3+0.3+0.3
0.8999999999999999
```

But in comparing to `int`s and/or `<` or `>` operations, you shouldn't worry.

In your update, we can use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module to show the cause:

```
>>> Decimal(1.2000000000000001)
Decimal('1.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125')
>>> Decimal(1.20000000000000001)
Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')
```

But does this really matter? It's an inherent problem with floating point numbers, but only matters where you need really high precision.

Comment: Regarding your last point: This is why some Python IDEs will warn you when you compare float expression for equality. It is better to use something like numpy's `isclose` instead of directly comparing.

Comment: @antonagestam "At all" is probably poorly worded, "directly" is probably more accurate.

Comment: Comparing ints and floats can also lead to problems, don't do this!