# Trouble comparing 2 excel sheets in Python using nested for loop

Tags: python, excel, loops, xlrd

Using python 3.4 and I have a problem with a small part of a larger program I am working on. For this part I need to compare column A of two excel sheets 'Bookings.xlsx' and 'Forced.xlsx'.

Column A contains booking numbers in both sheets, bookings.xlsx contains the data I need (in the same row) for every booking number in forced.xlsx

Here is the part I'm having trouble with.

```
reloc_sheet = reloc_book.sheet_by_index(0)
forced_sheet = forced_book.sheet_by_index(0)
bookings_sheet = bookings_book.sheet_by_index(0)

forced_rentals = []
for force_row in range(4,forced_sheet.nrows): #row 0:3 are headers
        Fnum = forced_sheet.cell(force_row, 0)
        for book_row in range(1,bookings_sheet.nrows): #row 0 is a header
                Bnum = bookings_sheet.cell(book_row,0)
                if Fnum == Bnum:
                        booNum = str(bookings_sheet.cell(book_row,0))
                        renCODate = bookings_sheet.cell(book_row,2)
                        renCOLoc = str(bookings_sheet.cell(book_row,4))
                        renUnit = str(bookings_sheet.cell(book_row,13))
                        renAgent = str(bookings_sheet.cell(book_row,12))
                        forced_rentals += [[booNum,renCODate,renCOLoc,renUnit,renAgent]]
```

So as far as I understand, this should look at the each booking number in the 'forced' sheet (variable Fnum) and compare it against the 'bookings' sheet (variable Bnum) and when it finds a match it will add the appropriate data from that row to the list 'forced_rentals'.

The problem is that after this loop has finished, the list is empty but it should have found 632 matches and therefore contain 632 nested lists. I'm sure it's a really simple solution but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. First of all here is the snippet of code which now works:

```
forced_rentals = []
for force_row in range(4,forced_sheet.nrows):
        Fnum = forced_sheet.cell_value(force_row, 0)
        Fnum_type = type(Fnum)
        if type(Fnum) is float:
                Fnum = str(Fnum)
                Fnum = Fnum.replace('.0','')
        if Fnum[-2:] == '/1':
                Fnum = Fnum.replace('/1','')
        for book_row in range(1,bookings_sheet.nrows):
                Bnum = bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,0)
                Bnum_type = type(Bnum)
                if type(Bnum) is float:
                        Bnum = str(Bnum)
                        Bnum = Bnum.replace('.0','') 
                if Bnum[-2:] == '/1':
                        Bnum = Bnum.replace('/1','')                
                if Fnum == Bnum:
                        booNum = str(bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,0))
                        renCODate = bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,2)
                        renCOLoc = str(bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,4))
                        renUnit = str(bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,13))
                        renAgent = str(bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,12))
                        forced_rentals += [[booNum,renCODate,renCOLoc,renUnit,renAgent]]
                        break
```

1) An all number `Bnum` or `Fnum` variable would either be a string eg '7123456' or a float 7123456.0 which wasn't being recognised as the same value. Converting to string by would simply make the float '7123456.0' again not the same. I solved this by:

```
if type(Fnum) is float:
                Fnum = str(Fnum)
                Fnum = Fnum.replace('.0','')
```

This converts a float to a string and removes the '.0'

2) Next issue came when I realised that not all booking numbers (`Bnum` and `Fnum` variables) will include a /1. Rental 7123456 and rental 7123456/1 are the same but our report server (which generates the excel sheets) will use the two interchangeably meaning the forced sheet may have 7123456 and the booking sheet have 7123456/1. In order to compensate for this I added this:

```
if Fnum[-2:] == '/1':
                Fnum = Fnum.replace('/1','')
```

This will look for any booking number ending with '/1' and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `cell()` to `cell_value()`,

```
Fnum = forced_sheet.cell_value(force_row, 0)
Bnum = bookings_sheet.cell_value(book_row,0)
```

or casting the types of `Fnum` and `Bnum` to `str` will compare them based on their content strings.

```
if str(Fnum) == str(Bnum):
```

Take note that `cell()` returns a `xlrd.sheet.Cell` object.

And `Cell` class of xlrd doesn't have `__eq__()` and `__ne()__` to support equality operators. Read more here: [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**ne**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__)

You can take a look at xlrd's source here, https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/sheet.py.

**From [The xlrd Module](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet-class):**

> **cell(rowx, colx) [#]**
>
> *Cell object in the given row and column.*
>
> **cell_value(rowx, colx) [#]**
>
> *Value of the cell in the given row and column.*

Because of that, the types of `Fnum` and `Bnum` is `xlrd.sheet.Cell`, not `str`.

```
>>> type(Fnum)
<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>
>>>
>>> type(Bnum)
<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>
```

But in using `cell_value()`,

```
>>> type(Fnum)
<class 'str'>
>>>
>>> type(Bnum)
<class 'str'>
```

Then you can compare them based on their string values.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation on the difference between cell() and cell_value(). I changed cell to cell_value and still have the same problem, I also tried if str(Bnum) == str(Fnum) which didn't work either. I tested with print(Bnum) and print(Fnum) in each loop and in each iteration the variable is assigning to the correct cell value.

Comment: @user3514222 Have you tried using `cell_value()` in assigning to `booNum`, renCODate`, `renCOLoc`, `renUnit`, and `renAgent`?

Comment: yes changed those also. I just ran through the debugger in wing IDE and may have found the problem. I inserted a row in each sheet with the same booking number (so I don't need to step over each iteration until it finds a match). In the stack data on the line where Bnum is compared with Fnum, Bnum="7070129.0" and Fnum="7070129" and therefore don't match. How can I remove the decimal considering some booking numbers start with "W", "R" or "B" followed by 7 numbers?

Comment: You don't need to convert it. `7070129.0` == `7070129` after all ( [check this answer to find out why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10037135/4895040) ). But if you really want to convert it, `int(Bnum)` is the way.

Comment: Of course, Bnum and Fnum were converted to a string so '7070129' didn't equal '7070129.0'.

I've used the following to check if a booking number contains only numbers and then not convert it to a string. Also some bookings contain a '/' just to make it more difficult.

if Fnum.startswith('W') == False and Fnum.startswith('B') == False and Fnum.startswith('R') == False:
                if '/' not in Fnum:
                        Fnum = int(Fnum)

Now the 'test' booking' number I entered is being added to the list but not the other 632.