# Why is 2.0==2 True in Python even though 2.0 is float and 2 is int

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, integer, boolean-operations

Why is `2.0==2` True even though `2.0` is `float` and `2` is `int`?

```
print(2.0==2)
```

output:

```
True
```

Comment: Well, isn't two equal to two? :)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037115/comparing-a-float-and-an-int-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Well, `2.0` is just a decimal representation of `2`, so `2.0 = 2`. If, however, we are dealing with strings, then `'2.0' != '2'`. I hope that helps.